# Powershell: validate URL path, incorrect path vs non public path

Tags: powershell, url

I am trying to validate a URL that, if valid, I will use to download a file. But I want to validate the domain and the full path BEFORE doing the download, so I can provide a meaningful error log.
Given paths like the following

```
www.validDomain.com/downloads/validDownload.zip
www.validDomain.com/downloads/invalidDownload.zip
www.invalidDomain.com/downloads/validDownload.zip
```

I want to be able to report

```
invalid path: /downloads/invalidDownload.zip
Invalid domain: www.validDomain.com
```

I can use

```
$uri = [System.Uri]$path
if (Resolve-DnsName -Name:$uri.host) {}
```

to test the domain. I can then use

```
if (Invoke-Webrequest $uri.OriginalString -DisableKeepAlive -UseBasicParsing -Method:head) {}
```

to test the full path without actually doing the download, but the only error I get is `The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.`, both when the path doesn't exist and when the path does exist but it isn't a publicly available path.
Is there any way, on the PowerShell side, to differentiate the permissions issue vs the incorrect path issue?
Or do I have no choice but to provide a wishy washy error in the log? I know effetely the path does not exist to the user who doesn't have permissions, I am just hoping there is some client side way to differentiate. But I may be running into the limitations of how the web has been implemented.

Comment: Provide correct credentials if you want to distinguish between lack of access vs lack of resource existence

Comment: Per @MathiasR.Jessen - the server isn't going to tell you whether or not a *private* resource exists unless you give it valid credentials to access the server first, otherwise it would be leaking information about its contents to anyone with network connectivity. Once you've given valid credentials you'll either get a HTTP 200 (OK) or HTTP 404 (Not Found) depending on whether the resource exists or not. If you only want to test if the resource exists and not actually download it you can use the "HEAD" method instead of "GET" (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD)

Comment: Um, yeah, now that you point it out it's pretty obvious that the server shouldn't tell me a private path doesn't exist. I guess I wish it could tell me I need credentials if so, and that the path doesn't exist if it's either a public path or I have provided credentials. Not a big deal though. I can live with a slightly wishy washy log. :)

Comment: It’s doing all that - HTTP 403 means it’s a private url that you need to specify credentials to get access to (without disclosing whether the resource exists or not), and an anonymous request to a public resource *and* an authenticated request to a private resource will give a HTTP 200 if it exists or a HTTP 404 if it doesn’t exist. Which combination of “authenticated: yes/no” and “resource exists: yes/no” are you trying to improve your logging for?